# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. The Solution installation failed

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package, deploy

I have created a new sharepoint 2013 project to add custom site columns by following these steps https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx

now i want to deploy the solution to another server. so i did the following steps:-

1. after successfully building the SP project inside VS 2012.
2. i copied the generated .wsp file found under the following location

> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\customFields\customFields\bin\Debug

then i run the following command to deploy the solution on the new server :-

```
stsadm.exe -o addsolution -filename C:\customFields.wsp
```

but i got the following error :-

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   C:\customFields.wsp: The Solution installation failed.

can anyone adivce on this please ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using stsadm to deploy a 2013 solution?

Comment: Also, you are aware that you are building a sandboxed solution, so make sure the User Code Host service is up and running

Comment: @RobertLindgren i always use this and it work fine for me .. can you adivce why i sohuld not use this ?

Comment: For deploying sandboxed solution you should refer "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2010/10/28/how-to-install-sandboxed-solution-with-powershell-sharepoint-management-shell.aspx" link

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela can not access you link..

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2010/10/28/how-to-install-sandboxed-solution-with-powershell-sharepoint-management-shell.aspx

Comment: Visit above link

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela now inside my site collection i wen to "site setting>> Gallery >> solution", then i browse to the .wsp file and i deply it. then i went to "site features" and i active it .. is this process consider valid ?

Comment: Yes for sandbox solution this is an ideal way to deploy this. But if you want his process as automatism like PowerShell then you should follow above link

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela ok now as i mentioned for my project i copied the .wsp file found under my "bin>>debug" visual studio project and i upload it to the site collection >> gallery >> solutions. this have created a new entry inside the "site feature" section so i activate this feature ,, but the custom column were not created ...

Comment: @RobertLindgren why i can not use stsadm method,, as i need those site columns inside many site collections. so i want to deploy them globally .. and then activate this feature on site collection basis when needed...

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela now i am bit confused ,, on what are the differences between deploying this solution globally and activating it from the "CA >> system Setting >> Manage farm solutions" ? and between uploading it to the site collection gallery ? is the difference in the type of solution or the main difference is that i first method will make this solution available globally to all site collections , while the later approach will make the solution available only to certain site collection ?

Comment: You should probably not use a sandboxed solution if that is your demand..

Comment: now i want to create new custom site columns ,, and inside this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx they mentioned that i need to create sandboxed solution for this  ... can you adivce please?

Comment: @RobertLindgren can you please adivce why i should not use sandboxed solution to create new site columns ??

Comment: Giving that you say you want to deploy them "globally". A sandboxed solution is deployed at site collection level. So future upgrades would be more complex. But surely, you could use a sandboxed solution together with a content type hub (only deploying the solution on that site collection) and get a decent maintainabilty anyway!

Comment: @RobertLindgren ok thanks for this reply. now inside the MSDN documentations they mentioned to create a sandboxed solution when creating site column https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx but they did not mention how to deploy t. so i assumed that i can deploy it by uploading the wsp file to the site collection gallery. so what are the other approaches that i can follow ? should i create a farm solution instead of sandboxed solution inside Visual studio ?

Comment: @RobertLindgren but if i want these new custom site columns to be available to only specific site collections (which is normal that site collections have different custom site columns) then i can create a sanded-box solution ? second question can i follow the same steps mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx for creating a new site columns but define the project to be Farm instead of sandboxed ??